# Python function to create random numbers

Tags: python

I have a quick question about a function I've been writing. It goes as follows. The code within it works but for some reason it doesn't run. Besides that I'm trying to make another piece of code below it so it outputs four times.

```
def genDigit()'             
    import random'                  
    digit = (random.randint(0, 9))' 
    print(digit)'                   

genDigit()
```

EG, Function alone, will run and output 1 random number. >Call function, then it outputs 9 for instance

Second part, code is written to call function so that 4 number are outputted in a list >call function 4 times or something so that it outputs the 4 numbers in a list, like 9, 5, 6, 7.

Also, the code within the function run but when I stick it in the function and call it it doesn't run. What am I doing wrong here?

From a newly made python programmer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to return the random number for multi-purpose usage:

```
def genDigit():
    from random import randint
    return randint(0, 9)

digits = [genDigit(), genDigit(), genDigit(), genDigit()]
```

I actually don't recommend a function because there already is one:

```
digits = [randint(0, 9) for i in range(4)] # 4 calls in a list
```

Comment: You could use what's known as a list comprehension to simplify the list, but I didn't mention it for your own sanity.

Comment: @mshsayem Yes I didn't want to confuse him. He says he is a beginner. If he doesn't understand return values, then list comprehensions are off the table.

Comment: But you should have pointed out that `import`s should not be inside functions, which would have helped you make it clear that the function is *completely pointless*.

Comment: Hi guys, I understand the concepts of programming just new to python. Thanks so far for the solution. I have a question about it. With digits, is this a list? So you're setting the list contents to four instances of the output of gendigit?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I know that the function is pointless. It is really a single statement so it doesn't require a function. Nevertheless, the OP wanted a function.

Comment: @JaimieAlexanderPatel Yes, it is basically a list of four random numbers. As Jon said, you don't really even need a function because the randint is a function in and of itself.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Thanks for this. Now that I need to call the function, how can I do this?


I've tried typing genDigit() below the function to call it when I run it.

Comment: What do you mean? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi hi again, sorry for coming across as unknowledgable at programming but I've pasted to code into the python window and now I need to get it it to run to produce output. So I assume now the function is written it now needs to be called. How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh. All you need to do is the print command. Simply print your list and single digit with `print(digits)` and `print(genDigit())` respectively.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Just realised my mistake and fixed it before you said! It's a function so it returns output, I just assumed automatically it would print. Thanks for the help!